# losing changes after modifying html (DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, jakarta-ee, dom, netbeans

I am using netbeans with chrome extension (netbeans connector) , i created a jsp page like this :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>Form Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div align = "center">
        <form >
            <table border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name : </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Name" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password : </td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="Password" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age : </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="Age" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" style="float: right"/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="float: right" onclick="onSubmit()" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div align = "center">
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>


<script language = "javascript">
    function onSubmit(){
        var name = document.getElementsByName('Name')[0] ;
        var password = document.getElementsByName('Password')[0] ; 
        var age = document.getElementsByName('Age')[0] ;

        if(age.value >= 50){
            alert('You\'re too old !');
        }

        var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1] ; 
        var body = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0] ;
        var  trNode = document.createElement('tr') ; 
        var thNameNode = document.createElement('td') ; 
        var nameTextNode = document.createTextNode(name.value.toString()) ; 
        thNameNode.appendChild(nameTextNode) ; 
        var thAgeNode = document.createElement('td') ; 
        var ageTextNode = document.createTextNode(age.value) ; 
        thAgeNode.appendChild(ageTextNode) ; 

        trNode.appendChild(thNameNode) ; 
        trNode.appendChild(thAgeNode) ; 

        body.appendChild(trNode) ;
    }
</script>
</body>
```

the function **onSubmit()** is supposed to add a row in the table dynamically, but when i run on the browser the changes appear briefly and i am redirected again to original page , what is exactly the problem?

Comment: Use `type="button"` instead of `submit`

Answer (score 0):

Form gets submitted on `onSubmit` function, you can prevent it by `return false`.
So below should work

```
 function onSubmit(){
    var name = document.getElementsByName('Name')[0] ;
    var password = document.getElementsByName('Password')[0] ; 
    var age = document.getElementsByName('Age')[0] ;

    if(age.value >= 50){
        alert('You\'re too old !');
    }

    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1] ; 
    var body = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0] ;
    var  trNode = document.createElement('tr') ; 
    var thNameNode = document.createElement('td') ; 
    var nameTextNode = document.createTextNode(name.value.toString()) ; 
    thNameNode.appendChild(nameTextNode) ; 
    var thAgeNode = document.createElement('td') ; 
    var ageTextNode = document.createTextNode(age.value) ; 
    thAgeNode.appendChild(ageTextNode) ; 

    trNode.appendChild(thNameNode) ; 
    trNode.appendChild(thAgeNode) ; 

    body.appendChild(trNode) ;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have few options to achieve this.

1. Use `type = 'button'` instead of `type= 'submit'`
2. Use `return false` in click handler. Not to forget `return` in inline event binding. e.g. `onclick='return onSubmit()'`. [**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/wrj71tek/)
3. Use `e.preventDefault()` [**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/wrj71tek/1/)